# How to list all apache modules in windows command line? ( WAMP installed )

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, apache-http-server

I have WAMP installed and I would like to list all Apache modules using this command:

```
httpd.exe -l
```

but when I hit enter, list of modules ( as far as I could read ) appears and disappears quickly ( it opens separate command prompt window )

Is this right command to use and if yes, is there a way to prevent this window from closing?